# What is the () after val (i.e: val ()) keyword mean in this line of Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I was reading the Scarlet lib from Tinder. And I encounter this line in their demo project:

```kotlin
override fun fromMessage(message: Message): Bitmap {
    val (bytes) = message as Message.Bytes // <---- What is the val () bracket mean?
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
}
```

What is this `val (bytes) = xxx` mean?

For context, this is the Message.Bytes Class:

```kotlin
sealed class Message {
    data class Text(val value: String) : Message()

    class Bytes(val value: ByteArray) : Message() { //<----
        operator fun component1(): ByteArray = value
    }
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html?

Comment: Damn, thank you. My bad for not checking the doc. @jonrsharpe